# Keydown not firing on page loaded in <object> element

Tags: javascript, html

I've a page containing CreateJS media, which gets embedded in another page via an `<object>` element. At some point in the timeline, I have my TweenJS code attach a `keydown` event listener to `document` which adds text to an object on the stage accordingly, since CreateJS doesn't offer support out of the box for keyboard events.

This works absolutely fine if I launch the media page on its own, but when I embed it, the keyboard events don't fire. I've tried adding a -1 or a 0 tabindex to the canvas element and calling `focus()`, which mostly works - until backspace is pressed, which causes IE to go back a page in the history. Calling `KeyboardEvent.stopPropagation()` doesn't seem to prevent this behavior.

I don't really have the option of using an `<iframe>` instead of `<object>` because the `<object>` is being generated by other code.

I have to support IE 11 and Edge, and it's not working right when embedded in either browser.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem ended up being that I didn't properly stop the propagation/bubbling of the event. I was calling just `KeyboardEvent.stopPropagation()` and nothing else. This snippet provided by a coworker fixed it:

```js
function (event) {
    if (event.stopPropagation) event.stopPropagation();
    if (event.preventDefault) event.preventDefault();
    event.cancelBubble = true;
    event.returnValue = false;
    // Event handler logic goes here...
}
```

This was overlooked because the behavior I was seeing suggested that the canvas never received the `KeyboardEvent` for the backspace key, and that IE was intercepting it (i.e., the browser went back a page without any changes to the canvas - I would have expected the key event to be handled and the canvas to render its changes before that happened).